# Keeping messages in queue for retry untill processed successfully

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I'm using Spring amqp MessageListener implemetation for handling messages. The bean definitions and working example is as follows.

```
public class AutomationMessageListenerServiceImpl implements MessageListener {

 public void onMessage(Message message) {
        EntityMessage message= null;
        try {
            message= jsonDeserializer.covertPayload(message.getBody());
            dispatchToHandler(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}





<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory">
        <rabbit:listener queue-names="${listen.queue}" ref="messageListener"/>
    </rabbit:listener-container>

    <bean id="messageListener" class="com.tcl.gvg.itsm.automation.core.messaging.AutomationMessageListenerServiceImpl"/>
```

The problem here is, I'm handling all the errors in the catch block hence the queue thinks I processed the messages successfully. However, I cannot throw Exception because the parent interface will cause problem as it doesnt throw any Error.

Is there a way I can do this without doing much code changes myself?

Comment: For example if I send a malformed json, the message should have been kept in the queue until admin takes action, but that's not the case with the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped the exception with a RuntimeException and thrown it to it's caller.

```
catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by

> because the parent method will cause problem

The container calls `onMessage()` and your other code is not involved. In any case, even if you requeue it, the message will be immediately redelivered.

For a fatal error like badly formed JSON, you should probably set up a dead-letter exchange/queue and route the message there by throwing an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`.

Or, use a `RabbitTemplate` to send the bad message to the DLQ.

Comment: MessageListener interface which has the onMessage() contract method doesnt throw exceptions. So I had to throw RuntimeException to stop the message from being acknowledged